# Enforcing DRY through the use of two almost identical generic db access classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns

Suppose that I have a business logic layer, in which I have made something similar to a repository pattern. Each class in my repository extends the same generic class, in which i have basic CRUD operations.

I have run into a problem, where I need to write the same logic for the tables in my database, where I have a many-to-many relationship - which I probably have 5 places in my ORM.

Initially, I thought about putting this logic inside the generic class to enforce DRY - However, this may be a very bad idea, since my non-many-to-many tables will be able to access these specific methods as well.

Another approach, would be to include this logic within each of my repository classes, meaning that i then would have to repeat my code - naturally I don't like that.

Therefore, this is more of a design question. But I would really like to know, how you believe this could be solved in order to make my code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a generic many to many repository class and a generic one to many repository class. This allows you to promote dry and provide reuse for the same logic.

Have just a standard base repository class in which many to many and one to many overrides the crud operations. Use the unit of work pattern to pass the objects to the generic repository class and subclasses.

If you are using entity framework then the dbcontext is your unit of work and dbset is the repository. You don't need a repository layer with entity framework.

This is how we do it where I currently work and it's very clean. We generate the raw SQL from the repository class depending on which database you are hitting such as MSSql, Oracle or DB2. Heck we even do this with web services where we have a web service repository which passes crud operations to some third party application, middleware or standalone service.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) That's basically what i did so far actually. I will go ahead and create a generic many-to-many generic class - good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a record is for a join table or not would usually only matter on lookups (because you would need to know whether it was a primary key or a composite key).

So, if you want to remain DRY, you can just use Entity Framework's `Find<T>` method. It takes an array of key values (which would just have one element for non-join tables).

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find

If you'd prefer to use `SingleOrDefault`, `FirstOrDefault`, etc., just change your methods to take an `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate` parameter. Then your callers can specify how they need to lookup the records.

On another note, if you put the type parameter  on the methods instead of the class, you don't have to have a bunch of classes extending the same class - you can just have one class.